# Export from Python to .xls

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, xlwt

I wanted to get output like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PByYv.png)

I am able write this code and its working fine. Being a beginner, I seek your criticism on this code. I feel its too lengthy.

## 1. If there is any short way, please let me know

## 2. Doubt:

I dont know why I am getting this error `Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'numpy.int32'>`, when i change this line `values=[a*1., a*1.]` to `values=[a, a]`. Why cant it export integers ? Similar logic works here:

```
for row, (name, value) in enumerate(zip(names, values)):
    sh.write(row, col, name);
    sh.write(row, col+1, value);
```

## Main working code:

```
import numpy as np
import xlwt #THIS MAY BE GOOD
#from pandas import DataFrame

amin =2
amax=10
da = 2
names = ['amin', 'amax', 'da']
values = [amin, amax, da]

fname='EXPORTexample.xls'; sheetname = 'sheet 1'

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sh = book.add_sheet(sheetname)

col=0;
# FIRST WRITE THE VARIABLES AND THEIR VALUES INTO XLSX.
for row, (name, value) in enumerate(zip(names, values)):
    sh.write(row, col, name);
    sh.write(row, col+1, value); 

t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 1)
amat= np.arange(amin,amax,da)

fn=np.zeros((np.shape(t2)[0],1))

col=3;
#row_eps =0;
#row_Dt += row_eps;

for a in amat:
    fn = a*t2

    names = ['eps_dot', 'Delta_t']
    values=[a*1., a*1.]  
    #write specific a conditions on every data curve/set   
    for row, (name, value) in enumerate(zip(names, values)):
        sh.write(row, col, name);
        sh.write(row, col+1, value); 

    #write names such as strain, stress, d11s, d_dot, d11
    occ_rows = len(names)#no.of occupied rows. 
    names = ['strain', 'stress', 'd11s', 'd_dot', 'd11']
    for cols,name in enumerate(names):
        sh.write(occ_rows+1, col+cols, name)

    ## WRITE actual numbers
    for rows, (strain_i,stress_i, d11s_i, d_dot_i, d11_i) in enumerate(zip(fn, t2, fn, t2, fn)):

        sh.write(occ_rows+1+rows+1, col, strain_i)    
        sh.write(occ_rows+1+rows+1, col+1, stress_i)    
        sh.write(occ_rows+1+rows+1, col+2, d11s_i)    
        sh.write(occ_rows+1+rows+1, col+3, d_dot_i)    
        sh.write(occ_rows+1+rows+1, col+4, d11_i)    

    col+=6 #incremening column value to avoid overwriting and related error

book.save(fname)
```

Comment: The exception may be due to the fact that `values=[a*1., a*1.]` effectively changes the value of `a` into a data type the `xlwt` module understands—a normal Python floating point value—whereas `values=[a, a]` results in it being passed objects of type `numpy.int32`, which it does not. Try `values=[int(a), int(a)]`.

Comment: @martineau, noted. It means, xlwt is not designed to deal with int32 and takes only python data type (float/int). edit: and its not the wrong habit of my programming practice.

Comment: Incompatible data type issues are common when working with multiple modules. If you want the rest of your code reviewed, I suggest you post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: Thankyou. I don't know there is something separate page is there. Thanks !

Comment: To link: here is my code   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134961/export-data-from-python-to-spreadsheet